# Ubuntu - killed process

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running this command:

```
find . -type f -delete
```

however Ubuntu keeps killing the process. Here's the output from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 11 19:54:14 hostname kernel: Killed process 29402 (find) total-vm:574220kB, anon-rss:513436kB, file-rss:580kB
```

Has this process exceeded some Ubuntu / Linux limit? And, if so, is there a better method than offered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077637/343204?

Comment: That can't possibly be the _only_ log entry.

Comment: Good point - I'd been gripping for 'Killed process'. The entry before was: `Mar 11 19:54:14 hostname kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 29402 (find) score 440 or sacrifice child` which explains everything.

Comment: You must have a very large directory structure to delete. Better use `rm -rf` instead.